# C# Interface Type Casting using Base class

Tags: c#, .net, class, .net-core, typecasting-operator

Hi I am wondering if it is possible to cast type in Interface and its concrete implementation in below way.

```
 public class BaseTypeClass

 public class BaseTypeV1 : BaseTypeClass

 public class BaseTypeV2 : BaseTypeClass

 public class BaseTypeV3 : BaseTypeClass



 public interface IProcessBaseType<T> where T : BaseTypeClass

      void Process(T baseType)



 public class ProcessBassTypeClass : IProcessBassType

      void Process(BaseTypeV1 data)

      void Process(BaseTypeV2 data)

      void Process(BaseTypeV3 data)
```

Comment: You would need `ProcessBassTypeClass` to implement all three variants of `IProcessBaseType<T>`, e.g `IProcessBaseType<BaseTypeV1>`, `IProcessBaseType<BaseTypeV2>` and `IProcessBaseType<BaseTypeV3>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as simple as doing this:

```
public class ProcessBassTypeClass : IProcessBaseType<BaseTypeV1>, IProcessBaseType<BaseTypeV2>, IProcessBaseType<BaseTypeV3>
{
    public void Process(BaseTypeV1 baseType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Process(BaseTypeV2 baseType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Process(BaseTypeV3 baseType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

An alternative that you might want to consider is this:

```
public interface IProcessBaseType
{
    void Process<T>(T baseType) where T : BaseTypeClass;
}

public class ProcessBassTypeClass : IProcessBaseType
{
    public void Process<T>(T baseType) where T : BaseTypeClass
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This allows for any object of type `BaseTypeClass` to be passed and allows `Process` to call `typeof(T)` to get the actual type at run-time. Useful if you want to dynamically build the list of processors that you have available.

---

Here's a simple example of how you can add type-specific processors at run-time when using the second code example:

```
public class ProcessBassTypeClass : IProcessBaseType
{
    private Dictionary<Type, Delegate> _processors = new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>();

    public void AttachProcessor<T>(Action<T> processor) where T : BaseTypeClass
    {
        _processors[typeof(T)] = processor;
    }

    public void Process<T>(T baseType) where T : BaseTypeClass
    {
        if (_processors.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            ((Action<T>)(_processors[typeof(T)])).Invoke(baseType);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I think I would actually go with the first example you have provided, since I have different work to be done for each version of BaseType classes :)

Comment: @user2662520 - Yes, but you can still have different work done for each version of the `BaseType` in the second example. You can create a `Dictionary<Type, Delegate>` to be able to store and retrieve the type-specific code. That allows you to build the processing at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such interface as `IProcessBaseType`, which is a different type from `IProcessBaseType<T>`.

If you add it as a common interface, you can make a solution:

```
public interface IProcessBaseType
{
    void Process(BaseTypeClass baseType);
}

public interface IProcessBaseType<T> : IProcessBaseType where T : BaseTypeClass
{
      void Process(T baseType);
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
public class ProcessBassTypeClass : IProcessBaseType
{
    public void Process(BaseTypeClass data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Processing as BaseTypeClass");
    }
    public void Process<T>(T data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Processing as generic with T = {0}", typeof(T).Name);
    }
}
```

Test program:

```
public class MyProgram 
{ 
    static public void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        var processor = new ProcessBassTypeClass();

        processor.Process( new BaseTypeClass() );
        processor.Process( new BaseTypeV1() );
        processor.Process( new BaseTypeV2() );
        processor.Process( new BaseTypeV3() );
    } 
}
```

Output:

```
Processing as BaseTypeClass
Processing as generic with T = BaseTypeV1
Processing as generic with T = BaseTypeV2
Processing as generic with T = BaseTypeV3
```

[Example on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4NNoHI)